# Is there a way to handle shared javascript assets in Spring?

Tags: javascript, spring

I'm familiar with MVC web frameworks and lately very familiar with Symfony2.

I want to start learning Spring, and the first practical problem I would like to try to solve is handling the reuse of javascript libraries.

It's been a while, but in Symfony2 my solution was to create a bundle with a Twig (template engine) extension which handled adding JS files (such as javascript frameworks) once even if aggregated content (from multiple bundles) had multiple statements requesting for the same js file. I believe I also used [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).

So, in the Spring world, is there a preferred way or built-in mechanism to deal with shared javascipt assets (or any other for that matter, e.g. images)?